# why doesn't my react app load fonts when using `type: 'asset/resource`? (loading fonts in a css file.)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm having an issue with my webpack application not loading fonts with `type: 'asset/resource'` honestly, it won't load many things that use `asset/resource` type but sticking to one issue :)

Here's my `webpack.config.js` file

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, './react-client/src', 'index.jsx'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './react-client/dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Project-Atelier',
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './react-client/src/index.html',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)?/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        loader: 'url-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

And my css file where I'm trying to import the font (the font I'm importing is indeed in the current folder. I placed it there to test.)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto-Regular';
  src: url('./Roboto-Black.ttf') format('truetype');
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto-Regular';
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

Here's some details on my dependencies. All should be up to date.

```js
// package.json
...

"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "uniqid": "^5.4.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.8",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.12.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.4.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "html-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "webpack": "^5.71.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
  }
...
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with babel but I could be wrong. EVERYTHING is working but importing fonts.I even tried changing css within the file I'm showing and changes worked. But not for fonts. An interesting observation I found is that I can't even add images with webpack using `type: 'asset/resource'` I have to use `use: 'url-loader'`

Been at this for a couple hours and still looking for answers.

Here's the error!

[Error output from webpack.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSDlL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my problem... in `module.rules` for `babel-loader`

on the line that has `test: /\.(js|jsx)?/` rewriting it as `test: /\.(js|jsx)$/` fixed the issue. It was just a single character that messed it up `?` when it should have been a `$`.